# Add a subdomain to existing nginx domain configuration?

Tags: nginx, certbot

I thought this would be a simple process, bu I cannot manage to get it up and running.

I have added a `A`-record on my domain manager, "dev.example.com".

I have made a new nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/dev.example.com`

This configuration contains the following (this is after I ran the certbot command):

```
server {
        root /var/www/html/dev.example.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name dev.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = dev.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name dev.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I ran `$ sudo certbot`, choose my domain and got a confirmation.

This is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` configuration file:

```
server {
    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status;
    }

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/example.com/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php {
#               try_files $uri =404;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = example.com) {
               return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And ofc I ran

- `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/dev.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
- `sudo nginx -t` and
- `sudo services nginx restart`

My end result would be to access `dev.example.com` with the same cert as for `example.com`